# Check Boxes to Open a Specific Activity

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I am developing an App using Eclipse. I have a page where it has different check boxes. I want the user if checking lest say options A and B and D then Activity 7 will open and if the user checks options A and C then Activity 5 will open.

Thank you

Comment: please share what you have tried

Comment: set onCheckedChangeListener()

Comment: @Neha Shukla please don't change the original question while editing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so like this:

Get the IDs of the checkboxes. Then add an `OnClickListener` to the checkboxes like so:

```
OnClickListener checkBoxListener;
checkBoxListener = new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if (checkboxA.isChecked() && checkboxC.isChecked())
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(this,Activity5.class)
            startActivity(i);
        }
        else if (checkboxA.isChecked() && checkboxB.isChecked() && checkboxD.isChecked())
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(this,Activity7.class)
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
};

checkboxA.setOnClickListener(checkBoxListener);
checkboxB.setOnClickListener(checkBoxListener);
checkboxC.setOnClickListener(checkBoxListener);
checkboxD.setOnClickListener(checkBoxListener);
```

Please give this a try.